# what will be a good way to write 10bits decoder?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a 10 bits binary to thermal decoder.

For a 4 bits decoder, it is relative straightforward as shown below. However, for 10 bits, is there a smarter way to do it instead of write 1000 line code.

```
module decoder(in,out);
   input [3:0] in;
   output [15:0] out;
//   input       enable;
   reg [15:0]        out;

   always @(in) begin
      casez(in) 
        4'h1: out=16'b0000000000000001;
        4'h2: out=16'b0000000000000011;
        4'h3: out=16'b0000000000000111;
        4'h4: out=16'b0000000000001111;
        4'h5: out=16'b0000000000011111;
        4'h6: out=16'b0000000000111111;
        4'h7: out=16'b0000000001111111;
        4'h8: out=16'b0000000011111111;
        4'h9: out=16'b0000000111111111;
        4'hA: out=16'b0000001111111111;
        4'hB: out=16'b0000011111111111;
        4'hC: out=16'b0000111111111111;
        4'hD: out=16'b0001111111111111;
        4'hE: out=16'b0011111111111111;
        4'hF: out=16'b0111111111111111;
       default: out=16'h0000;
      endcase
     end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could make this module fully parametrizable by using an unrollable for-loop. This loop would check for each bit of the `out` signal, if the loop-index is still smaller than the binary input signal.

The code would look like this:

```
module decoder #(
  parameter IN_W  = 10,
  parameter OUT_W = 1 << IN_W
)
(
  input      [IN_W-1:0]    in,
  output reg [OUT_W-1:0]   out
);

  integer i;

  always @* begin
    // Use an unrollable loop.
    for (i = 0; i < OUT_W; i++) begin
      // (in < i) returns a 1-bit value
      out[i] = (in < i);
    end
  end

endmodule
```

As you probably noticed, I also changed the way the ports are declared. In Verilog 2001—and also in more recent (System)Verilog versions—the port list and port declaration may be combined. This newer syntax, also known as ANSI-style, has the benefit that you don't need to add as much boilerplate code.

Comment: Hi Silicon1602 THanks for the reply. However, the code is only supported by the system verilog. It can not be synthesized.

Comment: For verilog move the 'i' outside the always,make it local to the module  `integer i; always @( * ) for (i=0...` I personally prefer `out[i] = (in < i); ` which makes more clear that `in<i` returns a one bit value. Beware that for large IN_W this may produce huge amounts of logic.

Comment: My bad, I am used to writing my RTL in SystemVerilog and forgot that declaration of the index must happen outside the for-loop. I fixed my RTL according to Oldfart's suggesting. (I also included his coding-style suggestion on `(in < i)`.)

Comment: Shouldn't `parameter OUT_W = 2 << IN_W` be `parameter OUT_W = 1 << IN_W`? With `IN_W` as 4, `2 << IN_W` is 32. Surely, it should be 16.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor yes, you are right. I meant to put `1 << IN_W`. Fixed it.